# LogicException after extending Sylius Variant model

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.3, sylius

I', trying to extend Variant model so I can add my fields on top of that to be used in the Product following the guide [here](http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/bundles/general/overriding_models.html).

and I got this error whenever I try to create a product

> The form's view data is expected to be an instance of class
>   Faumix\ProductPriceBundle\Entity\Variant, but is an instance of class
>   Sylius\Bundle\CoreBundle\Model\Variant. You can avoid this error by
>   setting the "data_class" option to null or by adding a view
>   transformer that transforms an instance of class
>   Sylius\Bundle\CoreBundle\Model\Variant to an instance of
>   Faumix\ProductPriceBundle\Entity\Variant. 500 Internal Server Error -
>   LogicException

here is my entity

```
<?php

namespace Faumix\ProductPriceBundle\Entity;


use Sylius\Bundle\CoreBundle\Model\Variant as BaseVariant;



class Variant extends BaseVariant{

protected $unitCost;

protected $landedCost;

protected $averagePrice;

protected $profitMargin;

protected $discountA;

protected $discountB;

protected $supplier;

protected $supplierCurrency;

protected $supplierPrice;

protected $reorderLevel;


/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function setUnitCost($unitCost)
{
    $this->unitCost = $unitCost;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getUnitCost()
{
    return $this->unitCost;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function setLandedCost($landedCost)
{
    $this->landedCost = $landedCost;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getLandedCost()
{
    return $this->landedCost;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function setAveragePrice($averagePrice)
{
    $this->averagePrice = $averagePrice;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getAveragePrice()
{
    return $this->averagePrice;
}


/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function setProfitMargin($profitMargin)
{
    $this->profitMargin = $profitMargin;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getProfitMargin()
{
    return $this->profitMargin;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function setDiscountA($discountA)
{
    $this->discountA = $discountA;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getDiscountA()
{
    return $this->discountA;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function setDiscountB($discountB)
{
    $this->discountB = $discountB;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getDiscountB()
{
    return $this->discountB;
}


/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function setSupplierPrice($supplierPrice)
{
    $this->supplierPrice = $supplierPrice;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getSupplierPrice()
{
    return $this->supplierPrice;
}


/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function setReorderLevel($reorderLevel)
{
    $this->reorderLevel = $reorderLevel;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getReorderLevel()
{
    return $this->reorderLevel;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function setSupplier($supplier)
{
    $this->supplier = $supplier;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getSupplier()
{
    return $this->supplier;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function setSupplierCurrency($currency)
{
    $this->supplierCurrency = $currency;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getSupplierCurrency()
{
    return $this->supplierCurrency;
}


}
```

and here is my entity xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping
                              http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd"
              xmlns:gedmo="http://gediminasm.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-extensions-mapping"
    >

<entity name="Faumix\ProductPriceBundle\Entity\Variant" table="sylius_variant">

    <field name="unitCost" column="unit_cost" type="float" nullable="true">
        <gedmo:versioned />
    </field>
    <field name="landedCost" column="landed_cost" type="float" nullable="true"/>
    <field name="profitMargin" column="profitMargin" type="integer" nullable="true"/>
    <field name="averagePrice" column="average_price" type="float" nullable="true" />
    <field name="discountA" column="discount_a" type="float" nullable="true">
        <gedmo:versioned />
    </field>
    <field name="discountB" column="discount_b" type="float" nullable="true">
        <gedmo:versioned />
    </field>
    <field name="reorderLevel" column="reorder_level" type="integer" nullable="true">
        <gedmo:versioned />
    </field>
    <field name="supplierPrice" column="supplier_price" type="float" nullable="true">
        <gedmo:versioned />
    </field>
    <field name="supplier" column="supplier" type="string" nullable="true">
        <gedmo:versioned />
    </field>
    <field name="supplierCurrency" column="supplier_currency" type="string" nullable="true">
        <gedmo:versioned />
    </field>
    <gedmo:loggable />
</entity>

</doctrine-mapping>
```

so far everything is ok , even I ran 
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force which updated the table

am not sure what went wrong , I event tried to extend the form , but I didnt add all fields

**EDIT 1**
I have extended the Form but I got Different error now

> Neither the property "unitCost" nor one of the methods
>   "getUnitCost()", "isUnitCost()", "hasUnitCost()", "__get()" exist and
>   have public access in class "Sylius\Bundle\CoreBundle\Model\Variant".
>   500 Internal Server Error - NoSuchPropertyException

and this the form class

```
namespace Faumix\ProductPriceBundle\Form\Type;

use Sylius\Bundle\CoreBundle\Form\Type\VariantType as BaseVariantType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;


class VariantType extends BaseVariantType  {


/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

    $builder
        ->add('unitCost', 'text', array(
            'data_class' => 'Sylius\Bundle\CoreBundle\Model\Variant',
            'label' => 'Unit Cost',
        ))
        ->add('landedCost', 'sylius_money', array(
            'label' => 'Landed Cost',
            'data_class' => 'Faumix\ProductPriceBundle\Entity\Variant'
        ))
        ->add('averagePrice', 'text', array(
            'label'    => 'average Price',
            'data_class' => 'Faumix\ProductPriceBundle\Entity\Variant'
        ))
        ->add('profitMargin', 'text', array(
            'label'    => 'profit Margin',
            'data_class' => 'Faumix\ProductPriceBundle\Entity\Variant'
        ))
       ->add('discountA', 'text', array(
            'label'    => 'discount A',
            'data_class' => 'Faumix\ProductPriceBundle\Entity\Variant'
        ))
       ->add('discountB', 'text', array(
            'label'    => 'discount B',
            'data_class' => 'Faumix\ProductPriceBundle\Entity\Variant'
        ))
       ->add('supplier', 'text', array(
            'label'    => 'supplier',
            'data_class' => 'Faumix\ProductPriceBundle\Entity\Variant'
        ))
       ->add('supplierCurrency', 'text', array(
            'label'    => 'supplierCurrency',
            'data_class' => 'Faumix\ProductPriceBundle\Entity\Variant'
        ))
       ->add('supplierPrice', 'text', array(
            'label'    => 'supplier Price',
            'data_class' => 'Faumix\ProductPriceBundle\Entity\Variant'
        ))
       ->add('reorderLevel', 'text', array(
            'label'    => 'reorder Level',
            'data_class' => 'Faumix\ProductPriceBundle\Entity\Variant'
        ))


    ;
}


/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver
        ->setDefaults(array(
//               'data_class'        => 'Faumix\ProductPriceBundle\Entity\Variant',
           'data_class'        => 'Sylius\Bundle\CoreBundle\Model\Variant',
            'validation_groups' => $this->validationGroups,
            'master'            => false
        ))
    ;
}

}
```

I have tried without defining the data_class but it seems it has no affect

I would appreciate if any one can help me in this

regards

Comment: I don't know Sylys but this doesn't sound like an entity problem but a form one. Do you use some form into your controllers related to this entity?

Comment: Thanks @DonCallisto , I do agree with you its not entity issue, as I was able to run doctrine command and updated the table, regarding if am using some into controllers , all I did is extended the entity and tried to extend the form to see if this is gonna solve my issue but it didnt ,I might missing the right form to extend. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Did you find where the issue was coming from. I have a similar one trying to extend another model in Sylius and I was just about going to try and extend the Variant model now.
Thanks

EDIT: this is actually working fine with the Variant model but I still have a problem with the ImagineBlockType in case anyone comes up with a solution (issue reported here https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/issues/2544)